# Algorithm to construct timeline graph with arrival and departure times

Tags: algorithms, graphs, synchronization, threads

So I am trying to construct a timeline graph for threads interacting with synchronization functions e.g. `pthread_mutex_lock`.

I have the following information:

1- thread ids

2- ids for the synchronization functions

3- Arrival times of the threads at the synchronization functions e.g. the time at which the thread encountered `pthread_mutex_lock`

4- Crossing time i.e. the time at which the thread crossed in to the critical section (e.g. crosses `pthread_mutex_lock`)

My idea:

1- Sort all the times (both arrivals and crossings)

2- for each time construct the event i.e. thread x arrived/crossed at synchronization y.

The questions:

1- The time complexity for this will be ***O(n log n)*** where n is the number of events (i.e arrival and crossing)?

2- Any possible imporvements/alternative ways/existing algorithms?

cheers!

Comment: Sorting takes $O(n\log n)$, unless you are using some tricks.

Comment: oh true, probably my brain wasn't functioning properly, so I thought O(n) is larger than O(nlogn). Let me fix it in the question. Thanks!